# хочу один тап вместо двойного на iphone!

Tags: css, ios, reactjs, scss, safari

Выявился неприятный баг, замеченный только на на айфонах (safari) и вроде бы как на реакте, если к элементу добавить псевдоселекторы after/before, то клик на этом элементе срабатывает только после второго тапа. То есть, первый тап подчеркивает ссылку, второй тап уже перекидывает по ссылке. На десктопе и андройде всё ок. Если убрать before и after то всё ок, либо если проверять не на реакте, то тоже всё ок. Как избавиться от такого поведения?

```
.link-animation {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;

  &::before{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 1px;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #333;
    transition: width .4s ease-in-out, left .4s ease-in-out;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -3px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 1px;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #333;
    transition: width .4s ease-in-out;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -3px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  &:hover::before {
    width: 50%;
    left: 0px;
  }

  &:hover::after {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.element {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    margin: 0 5px;
    color: #f54;
    transition: color ease .3s;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    @extend .link-animation;

    &:hover {
      color: #a54;
    }
}
```

Пример - https://jsfiddle.net/mxutzufz/2/

Comment: `.element { display: inline-block; }`?

Comment: не, это дичь какая-то